# How to generate acyclic random graphs in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I want to generate random acyclic graphs in the R igraph. I know that the function sample_pa generate for m=1 scale-free acyclic graphs according to the Barabasi-Albert model. I am interested if we can force igraph to generate acyclic graphs for higher values of m ? Or can we generate acyclic graphs according to some other algorithm in igraph R (or in some other R package) ? My aim is to generate acyclic graphs with different patterns of branching. Therefore, I am interested in these graphs.

Comment: Directed or undirected?

Comment: I am mainly interested in undirected graphs. But from directed graphs, it is always possible to obtain the undirected versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to generate random acyclic graphs in the R igraph.

> I am mainly interested in undirected graphs.

An acyclic undirected graph is a forest, i.e. a graph the connected components of which are trees.

> I know that the function sample_pa generate for m=1 scale-free acyclic graphs according to the Barabasi-Albert model. I am interested if we can force igraph to generate acyclic graphs for higher values of m ?

This is mathematically impossible. A tree on `n` nodes has `n-1` edges and a forest has fewer. For higher values of `m` in `sample_pa` there would be more edges, hence there would be cycles.

> Or can we generate acyclic graphs according to some other algorithm in igraph R

Look through the random graph generators in igraph. Several of them will output trees. For example, check `sample_growing` with `citation = TRUE`.

However, *none of these will sample trees uniformly*.  Presumably, instead of just generating *any* tree, you would want to know something about the distribution they are coming from.

Recently I contributed a uniform tree sampler, as well as a uniform spanning tree sampler to igraph, but it is not yet in the R interface. You can try it out with [the Mathematica interface](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) (or of course in C).

```
Table[IGTreeGame[10], 6]
```

[image]

```
grid = IGSquareLattice[{10, 10}];
HighlightGraph[grid, IGRandomSpanningTree[grid], GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide"]
```

[image]

> But from directed graphs, it is always possible to obtain the undirected versions.

But not *acyclic* ones.

It is easy to generate a random directed acyclic graph by randomly filling out the upper part of the adjacency matrix with the desired number of `1`s.

When you convert this to undirected, it will not usually be acyclic.

For example, this is not acyclic as undirected:

[image]

In fact, *any* simple undirected graph can be [oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(graph_theory)) so that the directed version will be acyclic. There is little relationship between undirected acyclic and directed acyclic graphs.

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. In the R igraph, besides the functions sample_growing ( ,m=1) and sample_pa( ,m=1), I did not find any other function which has as its output a tree.

Comment: @PiotrWilczek The one I mentioned is in the C core. I assume it will be in the next R interface.